# MySql Backup manager can not connect to 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I am trying to configure mysql backup manager for my mysql database,
but when I want to create a backup, I receive this error :

Got error 2005:

> Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3306' (0) when trying to connect

I am sure that the port, user and password are true.I have tried it with 'localhost' too but i receive the same error !

I have tested it in both windows 7 and windows 8 with admin access.

[image: mysql backup manager]

Comment: Try removing the port from your host

Comment: @ajtrichards : dear friend, it works without port number in my desktop, but in my real server my port number is different than default(its not 3306) and it doesn't work with only host name.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what your screen looks like when entering connection details?

Comment: @ajtrichards : The screenshot is now added.

Comment: Have you looked in the documentation how you use a different port?

Comment: @ajtrichards : i didn't find anything about it. so i decided to ask it on stackoverflow.